# How do I retrieve multiple rows from HBase using suffix glob, from a REST client?

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase, stargate

I have the following rows in a HBase table called `test`

`ROW                                   COLUMN+CELL                                                                               row1                                 column=cf:a, timestamp=1429204170712, value=value1
 row2                                 column=cf:b, timestamp=1429204196225, value=value2
 row3                                 column=cf:c, timestamp=1429204213427, value=value3`

I am trying to retrieve all the rows with rowkey matching prefix `row` using **Suffix Globbing**, as mentioned [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate)

But why do I get `Bad request` when I try `http://localhost:8080/test/row*` where `localhost:8080` is where the HBase REST server Stargate is listening, `test` is the table and `row` is a partial rowkey. I executed it in a browser and in a REST client Poster (Firefox plugin). Executing the URL `http://localhost:8080/test/row*/cf` gives the response `value1` but I would like to retrieve the values in all the rows with rowkey matching prefix `row`.

I am running HBase 0.94.26, Stargate (came bundled with HBase), Hadoop 1.2.1, Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine.

Is it possible to retrieve all the rows programmatically atleast?

Comment: Yes you can do it in java as well as in PHP. But I think Rest WS must work did you get chance to go through this link http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hbase/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/package-summary.html#operation_cell_query_multiple

Comment: Or just try this link first `http://localhost:8080/test/row.*` I just added dot before asterix.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I got it to work now. The missing piece was setting the Accept header in Poster to text/xml or application/json etc. Once I did that I got all the matching rows in the response. Please make your first reply as an answer so that I can accept it as the solution. The Cloudera link you shared helped me resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc REST works fine for retrieving all the rows. However you need to just modify the URL accordingly.
As per my opinion try the below comination on of them should work, Please note that that I have not yet tested.

```
http://localhost:8080/test/row*

http://localhost:8080/test/row
```

> Suffix Globbing
>
> Multiple value queries of a row can optionally append a suffix glob on
>   the row key. This is a restricted form of scanner which will return
>   all values in all rows that have keys which contain the supplied key
>   on their left hand side, for example:
>
> ```
> org.someorg.*
>     -> org.someorg.blog
>     -> org.someorg.home
>     -> org.someorg.www
> ```